# How to fix my solution code when it run as junit test

Tags: java, junit

Here is my solution code which has no problem

```
 public boolean hasAdjacentRepeats(String s){

       for(int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++){

               if(s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(i + 1)){
                   return true;


               }


       }
       return false;
   }
```

but at my solution code its like

```
@Test public void tests6(){
    code.Solution s =  new code.Solution();
    String input = "hhhhhey ";
    int expected = true;
    int actual = s.hasAdjacentRepeats(input);
    assertTrue("Expected was" +true+"but the actual was" +false  ,  expected == actual);
```

}

The first error is true. eclipse shows that change type of expected to boolean
The second error is `int actual = s.hasAdjacentRepeats(input)` same as the problem above.

So I do not know what is the appropriate way the fix my solution code.

Comment: Do you know what `int` means?

Answer (score 0):

Java does not support implicit conversions from `boolean` to `int` (like, e.g., [c](/questions/tagged/c) does. Thus, both `expected` and `actual` should be defined as `boolean`s, not `int`s.

On an unrelated note, since you're evaluating `s.charAt(i + 1)`, your loop should end at `s.length() - 1`, not `s.length()`, or else you'll get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Thank you so much I totally fix my problem!!